# Internal storage data disappeared, trying to dump

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, internal-storage, data-recovery

When I tried to use my SGS, it was unresponsive and didn't wake from sleep, then I rebooted it. After the boot, the desktop was like stock. I started checking my apps, some had its data intact and some lost all data. It seems that my data on the internal storage (NAND?) is gone. The internal SD card is ok.

The problem: I had hundreds of notes on the Notes app. I want to try to recover them.

The idea is to dump the internal storage raw data to the SD card (something like dd would do). My phone is not rooted.
Questions: any advices on this approach? Any ideas for a better approach?

Info:

- Not rooted. Using stock Android 2.2 froyo.
- Only a few apps installed.

Comment: If you're not rooted and completely stock there's probably not much you can do. You won't have permission to read from (the majority of) `/data`.

Comment: Thanks, but the access to the current Memo database file doesn't matter now, since it is empty. What I'm trying to do is get a dump of the internal storage raw data and save it to the SD card so I can search for the old Memo data there.

Comment: It should be possible to flash ClockWorkMod with Odin without being rooted (see [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1627299)). From there, you could access everthing on the device, and such also do a "raw dump".

Comment: Ah, and I knew I saw something before which might bring a little light in here: [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/recover-deleted-content-from-userdata-partition)