# Recovering deleted xml-file on old HTC wildfire

Tags: recovery-mode, restore, htc-wildfire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/recover-deleted-content-from-userdata-partition)

Before changing my phone i made a back up on my old HTC Wildfire, using SMS Backup & Restore. The program made a xml-file of the text messages. Unfortunately i forgot to copy the the file before resetting the phone and thus deleting all contents. I've tried Remo recover and Wondershare data recovery but they dont seem to recognize the xml-format (pictures and documents are shown). Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Hint: You might want to take a look at [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/)