# Copy application data file from internal memory to sdcard via update.zip script

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, pattern-lock

Unlock pattern has been used too many times on this android device and we don't have username and password. Most probably USB debugging might also be disabled. I can reset `wipe data/factory reset` from recovery mode, but I want to backup contacts and messages before I do that. Because we don't have username and password, so contacts can't be recovered even if it is synced to Google account (which I think won't be anyway). Only option I have is `apply update from sdcard` in recovery mode.

So is there any way to write some update script to copy the contacts data file to sdcard and then run it from update.zip?

Or if I can reboot the phone in USB debugging mode through update script as [it happens after flashing some kernels](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1219243#post16671001)?

Or if I can install [an APK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.thomascannon.screenlockbypass.pro) through update script?

Other details as below (in case if it matters)
**Device:** Samsung Galaxy S2
**Android version:** Never upgraded. So it is as it was bought.
**Root Status:** Unrooted

Comment: if you are in recovery, does adb work?

Comment: No, phone is not detected when I do `adb devices`. Even when I'm on lock screen.

Comment: See [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/cannot-unlock-tablet-as-have-no-internet-connection)

Comment: already gone through it. No username password so can't install Screen Lock Bypass. `adb` doesn't work. `null` funda also didn't worked for me. Phone call and then back button also didn't worked for me. Tried all possible things out of those..

Comment: Actually my phone is not getting detected by system even when on lock screen. When I connect USB, on Windows 7 it says driver installation for `SAMSUNG Mobile USB Composite Device` **failed**.

Comment: Try [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/recover-deleted-content-from-userdata-partition/25950#25950) BUT you will have the numbers and names... But if you are unrooted, then I think you're well and truly hosed! :( i.e. Factory reset it....

Comment: Still hope there, Try deleting the driver from windows first and restart it, then re-try plugging it in again...

Comment: I don't have CWM recovery. It's just simple recovery only 4 options. And yes it's unrooted phone. :-( . I will try deleting driver tomorrow. But once I've already done that. Still I'll try again.

Comment: I tried deleting driver and restart. :( No joy. Also I installed `kies` just in case if USB drivers are not properly installed by [this exe](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956)