# Personal data (contacts, sms, phone logs, settings, etc) gone after moving apps to a new microSD

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, external-sd, factory-reset, data-recovery

I've just bought a 16gb Sandisk microSD and I moved some apps to that by using the functionality available under `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications`. I went through the list and I moved some apps to the microSD when the button was available. I also moved the Music folder to the new microSD.

Then I left my phone for a while and when I came back it was asking me for the PIN code as it had restarted. Then the Android configuration wizard popped up, like when you first boot the device (so asking me to choose the language and set other configuration things). After this I found out that my previous data was gone including contacts, text messages, settings, etc. Similar to when you do a hard reset. Some things remained like pictures and music files.

Unfortunately there's no sync with Google or similar. I should have done that or at least made a backup before moving things to the new storage.

I believe my data is still there somehow. I'd like to know if my things are completely gone or maybe they are just not loaded for some weird reason. Can you help me?

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S Plus (GT-I9001) / Android version: 2.3.5

**EDIT**: After completely reformatting the microSD as also suggested by official SanDisk tecnical support for general problems, I didn't experienced another hard reset so far after moving files.

Comment: As you correctly tagged, your description fits a factory-reset -- which includes a wipe of user apps and data. So from your "internal storage", there's no easy way to restore anything, as its gone. However, the data you moved to your SDCard should still be there, as a wipe usually doesn't touch it. I just wonder what should have triggered such an "automatic factory reset" -- never heard such a thing before!

Comment: y indeed was really strange. do you know if there are some logs I can take a look at, hidden somewhere? (supposing they're not gone with the other stuff)

Comment: You suppose correctly: the logs will be gone for good with all the other stuff on internal storage. To my knowledge, there's nothing logging to SDCard by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) already correctly suggests, the description makes quite clear that such happened. A factory-reset "deletes" everything from your [internal-storage](/questions/tagged/internal-storage) -- that is, all the apps you've installed, all data, caches, etc. So nothing is left but what you've moved to SDCard/external storage.

While there are possibilities to even recover deleted data (usually via a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) or any other 1:1 copy of the entire file system and doing [file carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_carving)), this is nothing easy and you must start the copy as soon as possible, before you do any other initialization (which you already did). With every data change, chances to recover something get smaller. We have some questions/answers behind the [data-recovery](/questions/tagged/data-recovery) tag explaining this in more detail, see e.g.

- [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869/16575)
- [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25948/16575)

Btw: With all other data on [internal-storage](/questions/tagged/internal-storage), also the logs are gone for good -- which is a pity, as it would be very interesting to know what triggered an automatic factory-reset. The only thing coming to my mind is a [remote-wipe](/questions/tagged/remote-wipe), which might have been triggered either via your company (if you're accessing their [exchange](/questions/tagged/exchange) server via [active-sync](/questions/tagged/active-sync), and thus accepted the corresponding [device-administrator](/questions/tagged/device-administrator)) -- or the previous owner (if any) having set up some anti-theft app, and now pulled the trigger on you...

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I wouldn't say it was a remote-wipe as I exclude the two possibilities listed (especially the latter, as there's no previous owner). A friend suggested it might have been a sort of short-circuit when playing with the new microSD, which might have sent a reset signal somehow.

Comment: Never heard of a microSD sending a signal which caused a factory-reset. The remote-wipe was just a guess, I'm missing your full background to place a "hit" here :) // If my post answered your question, it would be nice to "accept" it (click the checkmark next to it), so it's recognizable as such. Thanx :)

Comment: which kind of background might be needed? :)

Comment: All account data (social networks, bank, whatever) including passwords and keys plus full authority :) What I meant to say is: While all details of what might have happened (and what is installed, how configured, how you've got the device, first/second hand, etc.) might be present to you, they are not present to me. Even writing a full story would not be the same as experiencing the thing yourself. Which leaves some guess-work.

Comment: Ok it happened again. I think it's something with the new microSD card. This time I was uploading some videos on that memory (using Airdroid). Suddenly I saw that the progress bar got stuck and when I looked at my phone I notice he had reset itself. And then, again, configuration wizard and what it's supposed to be another hard reset..

Comment: I'd suggest to try another SDCard (other brand) to figure out. It's nothing new that some combinations (SDCard/device) cause problems, though it's the first time I've heard of this special one. Checking Google for ["samsung galaxy s plus" sandisk](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=%22samsung+galaxy+s+plus%22+sandisk) if others share your problem with this combination (I've picked two with trouble on the first result page), and how they solved it (which other brand) might prove helpful.

Comment: y.. I'll try to borrow another microSD from friends. Meanwhile, I tried to completely format the one I have and see what would happen (I'm not particularly concerned about my stuff now, as all is gone and I'm syncing on google only few important contacts).
thank you very much for your useful support, so far :)

Comment: You're welcome -- and good luck! Don't forget to update us once you've found out something. Who knows who's next...