# SD Card Data Recovery with no root

Tags: data-recovery

My ZMAX Z970 can't be rooted, at least by me. I can't find where to do that.

I accidentally deleted some videos which were on my sd card.

I have not used the card too much since then and don't plan to until I get this resolved.

I can't find any undelete utility or method that a) is not a scam b) doens't need root access and c) actually works.

How can I do it?

**Meta:**

If you think this is a duplicate question, please make sure the duplicate actually has a viable answer to my question. Thanks!

The question pointed to as duplicate does not explain how to use the software on an Android phone or make it see the disk from the PC. I tried the software mentioned in that article and it does not see my phone, only local PC disks. Please enable a fresh answer that breaks it down step by step for SD card on no root android phone. Thanks.

Comment: See this as well. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61511/how-to-recover-data-from-lge-nexus-4-running-on-android-version-4-4-2/69132#69132

Comment: @Firelord, that's for a rooted phone. Right?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/data-recovery-how-to-restore-deleted-formatted-files-on-hd-micro-sd-card I added that in garb of this one. Apologies for that since you demanded no root method. But anyway, its still duplicate in reference to this new link.

Comment: Photorec (a part of Testdisk collection)(Windows application) did the job for me when I tested it on my friend's micro SD Card once. You may try it.

Comment: @Firelord, I'm glad it worked for you. Photorec does not see my SD card when I have my phone connected to the PC via USB. What should I do to make it see it? Thanks.

Comment: Photorec will not see it that way. Since its an external SD-Card, you can remove it and plug into the system. Run the software and it will detect. Otherwise, if any of your damaged storage cannot be removed, then you'll have to take a `dd` backup of it and let the software run through it.

Comment: @Firelord, ok so this is really not a duplicate question. I can't "plug it into the system". I don't have a card reader. So you are saying, there's no solution without buying a card reader? Thanks!

Comment: I actually already mentioned in my last comment. You can use `dd` to take an image of your SD-card into a OTG USB drive. For info to how to use `dd` see [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android/15880#15880). A user also mentioned about using `dd` [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android/15880#15880). They sure now will help you. The general idea of command is `dd if=sd-card_location of=OTG_USB_location/name.img`

Comment: @Firelord, thanks for the link. I tried googling dd to find out what it was and just got a bunch of porn links. :)