# USB storage damaged-it may need reformating Samsung galaxy SHW-M110S

Tags: data-recovery, storage

Accidently i removed battery from my celphone while the phone was intializing the internal memory. and now getting a notification that it may need reformatting but i am more concerned with the data i had on my phones internal memory.

How to recover data.

and please suggest how to get the problem fixed as it is also unable to show internal memory. it shows as unavailable.

Comment: W already have a bunch of related questions on this topic here. May I suggest you start with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) and the [questions tagged `data-recovery`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)? Especially follow up to [Recover deleted content from userdata partition](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25948/16575), as that's what your question basically is about. Then please return and let us know how you solved your issue, or where you're still stuck. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't post email in your question. I know you want an answer quickly, but that would defeat the purpose of SE. Nobody would know if you got your question answered or not, plus anyone else with your situation wouldn't know what to do. Follow what Izzy suggested in his comment. In the future make sure you make backups.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to reformat the partitions using odin (for samsung). It may have wiped out said partitions and erased the data on that partition. I am not sure if there is a way to recover, this is where a nandroid backup comes into play.