# How Recover deleted data from internal memory of non rooted Moto G device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, data-recovery, motorola-moto-g, delete

This is my first post here :). My question is to recover accidentally deleted data from a Moto G (the device is not rooted and has Android 4.4.4 inside) with avoiding any potential data loss.

So the trivial question will be must I absolutly root my device I'm asking that because the tool (Dr.Fone for Android) prompt me a message so that device must be rooted and it not succeed to recover deleted data. So if rooting is mandatory how achieve this without loss any data ?

Unfortunatly Moto-G seems to need a custom boot. I heard about clockworkmod, what if I cutom the boot of my device, can I still get my deleted data back after this operation

Suggestion may be clone internal memory of device with adb tool then use a data recovery tool :so my question will be first how backup internal memory of the device or clone it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have to backed up that data ?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already seen our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info)? As this is a frequent question type, we've setup some first-aid there. Especially follow-up to [Recover deleted content from userdata partition](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25948/16575). As for "cloning internal storage", [One Way to Use a Linux Computer to Recover Files from an Android Device](http://www.df.lth.se/~jokke/androidfilerecovery/) might be a good reading.

Comment: Niranth Reddy I don't know if it is a "backup" but I connected my device to my computer and I copied the containt of the Windows Explorer of the device to my computer. Thank you Izzy I will check now

Comment: That mention to reboot into ClockWorkmod Recovery. If I'm not wrong using ClockWorkmod mean that the device is rooted isn't it or is a ligth root method? Anyway putting a ClockWorkmod Recovery on device will it not result of sort of factory reset and if yes it will erase data on device or not ?

Comment: After looking well there are some solutions to backup all memory of the device:  
- using SDcard with a staticaly link busybox then use dd (unfortunatly Moto G has no sdCard slot inside)
- using JTAG communication (unfortunatly MOTO G has no pin and battery is not amovible)

Is anyone experimented to recover data on a non root Moto G ?
Thanks