# How to recover lost data after a factory reset in samsung note 3 SM-n900 series?

Tags: adb, samsung, recovery-mode, factory-reset, data-recovery

My Samsung Note 3 SM-N900 series got stuck in the bootloader loop, due to which I had to do a factory reset. The good thing is that my smartphone is out of the bootloader loop after the reset but all my private data including documents and pictures have been deleted.

I am trying to recover the data using testdisk in Redhat, but the results of deeper search through testdisk are not fetching anything back. So, I decided to shift to windows 10. I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhWbSM-630E) tutorial to recover the data back using testdisk in windows. The problem I am encountering is that when I connect my device in the computer, It does not show any "sdb" drives connected to it in the command line interface, But I am able to see and access my device in the graphical user interface "This PC".

How am I suppose to access this device through command line interface to proceed further? Also any other methods to recover the lost data are also welcome.

I am adding images of the output displayed by the testdisk tool on windows:
[for photo click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B56kG.jpg)
or

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

Image source: My personal computer

Comment: Please take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info), and [Recover deleted content from userdata partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25948/16575). You'll first need to create a disk image, as you cannot directly access the storage of your Android device from your computer anymore (no USB mass storage mode).